# Finding the limit of N approaching infinity: $N(x^\frac{1}{N}-1)\approx\ln(x)+\frac{1}{2N}\ln(x)^2+...$

Tags: calculus, limits, mathematical-physics, entropy

I am having trouble understanding the linked exercise, final paragraph (not parts a or b)

[Entropy Calc Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbj47.jpg)

**I understand this is a physics related exercise, however, my trouble comes in at the mathematical portion.**

The exercise is from *Thermodynamics and an Introduction to Thermostatistics* by H.B Callen, 2nd ed.

For the first part (a) I ended up finding the entropy to be

$$\Delta S=\frac{C_v}{N}\ln\left(\frac{T_N}{T_0}\right)$$

Note: (b) was found to be 0, however, I don't feel that is correct and will inquire to the physics SE if need be.

The problem statement is to now find the entropy change in the limit as $N\to\infty$, for large N:

$$N(x^\frac{1}{N}-1)\approx\ln(x)+\frac{1}{2N}ln(x)^2+...$$

This is where I am having trouble. Is it as simple as plugging in $ln(x)$ into the entropy equation, or is there more to it? The book mentions this is a nontrivial limit, which makes me doubt my suggestion below:

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{C_v}{N}\ln\left(\frac{T_N}{T_0}\right)=C_v\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{T_N}{T_0}\right)}{\ln(x)}\right)$$

I am not sure where to continue with this, any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. You may just observe that, as $N \to \infty$, we have
$$
x^{\large\frac1N}=e^{\large\frac{\ln x}N}=1+\frac{\ln x}N+\frac{\ln^2 x}{2N^2}+O\left(\frac1{N^3}\right)
$$ giving directly

> $$
> N(x^\frac{1}{N}-1)\sim\ln x+\frac{\ln^2 x}{2N}
> $$

as announced. We have used the Taylor expansion
$$
e^u=1+u+\frac{u^2}{2!}+O(u^3)
$$ as $u \to 0$.

Comment: Ahh, I see, the Taylor expansion was used to derive the $\lim_N\to\infty$ of the 'very large N' function. This would then lead to a $\Delta S$ of something like $$\left(C_v{\ln\left(\frac{T_N}{T_0}\right)}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\ln(x)}+\frac{2N}{ln(x)^2}+...\right)$$, correct?